# How to find the correct path for OPENXML function

Tags: xml, t-sql, openxml

I need to pull certain fields from an XML file into a SQL Server table but I cannot find the correct path that is specified in the openxml function in SQL Server.

How can I input the correct path (from the XML extract given) to pull any such field  ?

I want to pull the Id and InternalId field with the relevant data from identifer

I have brought in the XML document into a SQL Server table using openrowset.

I have also code to try pull one field from the XML but my path in the openxml function is wrong i.e. it keeps returning a blank.

```
    CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
    (
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XMLData XML,
    LoadedDateTime DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\ANRE\OneDrive - Ambu\Desktop\Operation Docs\XML\SinglePortalForm.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

    SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML




    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

    SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

    SELECT Id
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Forms/PortalForm/Identifer')
    WITH 
    (
    Id [varchar](500) 'Id'

    )

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
    GO


    It should be pulling Fields Id and InternalId 
    from the below: However I receive no error message, it just returns a blank


       <Identifier>
            <Id>4b68ac3d-70c7-4262-8245-c29be80f7e07</Id>
            <InternalId>17</InternalId>
            <IsReferenceValid>true</IsReferenceValid>
            <Name>ItemMarketingMakeForm</Name>
          </Identifier>



<FormFile xmlns="http//schemas.profisee.com/masterdatamaestro/2010/07" xmlnsi="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AssemblyVersion>6.1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
  <ServerURL inil="true" />
  <UserName>UULAN\DDFV</UserName>
  <Forms xmlnsa="http//schemas.profisee.com/masterdatamaestro/2010/09">
    <PortalForm>
      <Identifier>
        <Id>4b68ac3d-70c7-4262-8245-c29be80f7e07</Id>
        <InternalId>17</InternalId>
        <IsReferenceValid>true</IsReferenceValid>
        <Name>ItemMarketingMakeForm</Name>
      </Identifier>
      <MetadataStatus>Valid</MetadataStatus>
      <UpdateState>Auto</UpdateState>
      <ChangeAudit>
        <Created>
          <DateTime>2019-05-16T071250.897</DateTime>
          <UserId>
            <Id>fe0ea488-c98f-4a4d-aff4-cd8aa3c51915</Id>
            <InternalId>18</InternalId>
            <IsReferenceValid>true</IsReferenceValid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answwer is rather late, but you haven't got any answer yet...

There are several things to know:

First of all: `FROM OPENXML` (together with the SPs to prepare and to remove a document) is outdated and should not be used anymore.

Second: There is a *default namespace* declared (with `xmlns="SomeURL"`).

Try something along this to get the two field you mentioned. If you need anything else, just come back or start a new question.

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
 N'<FormFile xmlns="http//schemas.profisee.com/masterdatamaestro/2010/07" xmlnsi="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AssemblyVersion>6.1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
      <ServerURL inil="true" />
      <UserName>UULAN\DDFV</UserName>
      <Forms xmlnsa="http//schemas.profisee.com/masterdatamaestro/2010/09">
        <PortalForm>
          <Identifier>
            <Id>4b68ac3d-70c7-4262-8245-c29be80f7e07</Id>
            <InternalId>17</InternalId>
            <IsReferenceValid>true</IsReferenceValid>
            <Name>ItemMarketingMakeForm</Name>
          </Identifier>
          <MetadataStatus>Valid</MetadataStatus>
          <UpdateState>Auto</UpdateState>
          <ChangeAudit>
            <Created>
              <DateTime>2019-05-16T071250.897</DateTime>
              <UserId>
                <Id>fe0ea488-c98f-4a4d-aff4-cd8aa3c51915</Id>
                <InternalId>18</InternalId>
                <IsReferenceValid>true</IsReferenceValid>
              </UserId>
            </Created>
          </ChangeAudit>
        </PortalForm>
      </Forms>
    </FormFile>';
```

--First we will declare the namespace, then we will use `.value()` to retrieve a value from a given XPath:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http//schemas.profisee.com/masterdatamaestro/2010/07')
SELECT @XML.value('(/FormFile/Forms/PortalForm/Identifier/Id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS Identifier_Id
      ,@XML.value('(/FormFile/Forms/PortalForm/Identifier/InternalId/text())[1]','int') AS Identifier_InternalId;
```

--If the namespace might change, or if the `<Identifier>` might live in a different location, you could minimize the query like here

```
SELECT @XML.value('(//*:Identifier/*:Id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS Identifier_Id
      ,@XML.value('(//*:Identifier/*:InternalId/text())[1]','int') AS Identifier_InternalId;
```

The recommended approach is: "Be as specific as possible".